# How to keep js function run between different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder how sites like SoundCloud work: you play a song and it keeps playing even if you move to another page without stopping
Any suggestions?

Comment: This can be done using dynamic data and altering the url. Do you have a specific problem?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of is to build your app, or at least the parts of it that need to bo continuous, as a single page.

In practice, this means that only one HTML document is loaded. When, say, a link is pressed, the browser action is intercepted and prevented and the browser behaviour is faked by javascript.

Consider a website consisting of pages A and B. Normally, when a link pointing to B is activated, the URL is changed and the browser calls the server, requesting B. In a single-page application, however, this is interrupted by a javascript function, which changes the URL using the History API, and then displays B in a way that doesn't require a new document being synchronously fetched from the server.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways to do it.

**Navigate to a new page**

If you do that, a whole new JS execution context is created for the new page, so you can't keep the function running. What you can do however is to "resume" execution in the new page. For this you need to save the state of the old page either on the server or in some client storage that persists between page changes (cookies, localStorage, etc).

**Fake navigation**

This is the most user friendly way - you turn your website into a web application. You no longer have multiple pages, so when user wants to change what he sees in the browser (like go to a new song), the app simply changes the appropriate area with the desired content. This is a complex topic that should probably be researched in itself, not explained in a SO answer. Go ahead and google "single page application" and you should find plenty of resources for it.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you never change the page when you are using souncloud. You always stay on the same page and only the parts get changed which are actually changing, so you never reload the whole page. That's why they can keep the music playing: They just never remove or change the actual player. If you are wondering why the URL in your browser is changing if you never leave the page: They manipulate your [history entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries).
If you are interested in creating an application that behaves similar you should checkout frameworks like [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) or [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/). [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/) Gives a nice overview of those frameworks.